# slide up and down of a div animates its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#wrap').slideToggle();
  $('#inpsearch').focus();
});
```

```css
.wrap{
display:none;
background:gold;
}
.inpsearch{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>
<br>
<input type='text' class='inpsearch' id='inpsearch'>
<br>
</div>
```

Click on `button` and you'll see - some **unknown** top margin or padding animates without my intention.
The content of `wrap` should be fixed and only `wrap` itself should animate i.e. open and close.

Comment: Can you show your CSS settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be caused by the `.focus()` method, try calling `.focus()` after the toggle has completed by providing a callback like so:

```
$('#wrap').slideToggle(function() {
  $('#inpsearch').focus();
});
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#wrap').slideToggle(function() {
    $('#inpsearch').focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: none;
  background: gold;
}

.inpsearch {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='inpsearch' id='inpsearch'>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: that's it. unbelievable. could you explain, pls?

Comment: @qadenza I'm honestly not too sure why this happens. I just noticed that performing `$('#swrap').slideToggle();` by itself works, so I thought that the issue must be with `.focus()` occurring while the toggle occurs (as `slideToggle` is asynchronous). So I tried it with a callback to make sure it occurs after the toggle had occurred and it seems to work.